# relation between size of text and position in file

Tags: matlab, file

let us suppose that  we have following text file 'badpoem.txt', which contains  the following  sentences

```
Oranges and lemons,
Pineapples and tea.
Orangutans and monkeys,
Dragonflys or fleas.
```

i determined size  for each  sentence in bytes

```
 whos
  Name        Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  ans         1x1                 8  double              
  fid         1x1                 8  double              
  tline1      1x19               38  char                
  tline2      1x19               38  char                
  tline3      1x23               46  char
```

where  tline1, tline2 and tline3  are corresponding  texts, now when i  have opened file and  read text  three times, i have checked  current position of files, and here is result for first one

```
fid = fopen('badpoem.txt');
ftell(fid)

ans = 0
```

it is opening, so it's fine, now read first text

```
tline1 = fgetl(fid)  % read the first line
ftell(fid)

tline1 =

    'Oranges and lemons,'


ans =

    21
 now lets read second file
tline2 = fgetl(fid)
ftell(fid)

tline2 =

    'Pineapples and tea.'


ans =

    42
```

and finally last one

```
tline3 = fgetl(fid)
ftell(fid)

tline3 =

    'Orangutans and monkeys,'


ans =

    67
```

is there any relation between size of  text and  position?  thanks in advance

Comment: Windows? if so there are two chars (0xd 0xa) added to the end of each line, otherwise just one (0xa).  File position is reported after consuming the line and ending char(s)

Comment: yes system is windows

Answer (score 0):

For text files Windows adds a two characters at the end of each line, Other systems add one. Matlab, when reading a line skips these in the returned string but since Windows adds two instead of one you get different position values for Windows than is shown in the Matlab example here:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ftell.html

Char strings are saved in files using one byte for each character but are stored in Matlab's memory as 16 bit words or 2 bytes for each character which doubles the apparent size of char strings.

Comment: but  you know size is 38  byte right? position is 21, how they are connected?  for instance let   us suppose size  is 50 byte , what will be position?

Comment: Those are the sizes the string takes up in Matlab's memory. the ftell() refers so the position in the file. They aren't the same thing. Many systems store chars in memory using 2 bytes each as Unicode.

Comment: i think position is related to the length of text and not its  size in byte right?

Comment: Yes, the position in a file will be based on how it's stored in the file. In this case it's stored one character per byte.

Answer (score 0):

Very nice question, indeed. Actually, I think what confuses you is the fact that you are dealing with many different problems mixed up all together. Let's analyze them one by one.

---

**1) TXT File Format under Windows**

Usually (asian locales and advanced text editors are a common exception), text files under Windows are `ANSI` encoded (where `ANSI` is a generic way for referring to `ISO/IEC 8859` encodings). Within this encoding framework, on a binary point of view, each character is represented by a single byte. If you open such `TXT` files with `Notepad` and paste a few chinese ideograms inside, this is the message you will see when trying to save your changes:

> This file contains characters in Unicode format which will be lost if
>   you save this file as ANSI encoded text file. To keep the Unicode
>   information, click Cancel below and then select one of the Unicode
>   option from the Encoding drop down list. Continue?

**2) Line Separators under Windows**

As other users already pointed out, in Windows, the default line break is represented by a combination of two character: a carriage return (better known as `\r` or `0xD`) and a line feed (better known as `\n` or `0xA`). Here is an example based on your text:

```
Oranges and lemons,\r\nPineapples and tea.\r\nOrangutans and monkeys,\r\nDragonflys or fleas.
```

This doesn't happen with other operating systems like Linux and MacOS, in which only line feeds are supported:

```
Oranges and lemons,\nPineapples and tea.\nOrangutans and monkeys,\nDragonflys or fleas.
```

**3) Storage of Strings under Matlab**

Matlab stores characters in memory as `Unicode` 16-bit unsigned integers that take up two bytes each. This does not depend on the current Matlab encoding, (which can be retrieved executing the command `feature('DefaultCharacterSet')` and, by default, corresponds to the current operating system encoding).

**4) The fgetl Function**

As per [official documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html), the `fgetl` function reads a single line from a file (signally, a valid file handle) excluding line breaks. This means that Matlab reads the whole line, including all the line break characters, but they are trimmed out from the output string returned by the function.

The difference between `fgetl` and `fgets` is that the former trims the line breaks while the latter doesn't.

---

All this being said, let's analyze step-by-step what is happening in your code. First, you open the file and the pointer is being placed at the beginning of the stream:

```
fid = fopen('data.txt','r');
ftell(fid) % 0
```

Then, you read the first line:

```
tline1 = fgetl(fid)
ftell(fid) % 21
```

The line contains `19` characters (the size you get from the `whos` table) that, memory-side, are being stored using `38` bytes because of the Unicode. The `ftell` call displays the number `21` because `fgetl` read the whole line, which includes two line breaks characters that have been trimmed from the output (`0 + 19 + 2 = 21`).

Then, you read the second line:

```
tline2 = fgetl(fid)
ftell(fid) % 42
```

The line contains `19` characters that, memory-side, are being stored using `38` bytes. The `ftell` call displays the number `42` because `fgetl` read the whole line, which includes two line breaks characters that have been trimmed from the output. From the previous offset, `21 + 19 + 2 = 42`.

Finally, you read the third line:

```
tline3 = fgetl(fid)
ftell(fid) % 67
```

The line contains `23` characters that, memory-side, are being stored using `46` bytes. The `ftell` call displays the number `67` because `fgetl` read the whole line, which includes two line breaks characters that have been trimmed from the output. From the previous offset, `42 + 23 + 2 = 67`.